# converting phone number back to int64

Tags: c#

I have a phone number (000) 000-0000, I would like to convert it back to 0000000000, is there a way to do so?

Comment: Usually you would not want to store phone numbers in an integral type. You might loose leading zeros or non-numerical symbols (+).

Comment: Yeah what 0xA3 said, don't do this unless you know for sure you are only storing US phone numbers for which I don't believe any area codes start with 0.

Comment: Please, please, please Do not store a phone number as an int.  Nothing good can come of that.

Comment: @Jimmy: "0" as the first number calls the operator.  "1" as a first digit is the USA country code, so all area codes start 2-9.  (And until a few years ago, the 2nd digit was always 0 or 1)

Comment: Agreed with 0xA3. You can strip the characters into another string, which is a good idea for consistency and efficiency, but store it as a `VARCHAR` or equivalent type in your db. You may also want to allow `*` and `#` which are both valid phone symbols.

Comment: It may be valid for the US that phone numbers don't start with 0. But don't forget that numbering schemes may change and the way phone numbers are specified is clearly out of your control. What if they extend the spec to allow leading zeros (similar to allowing more than 0 or 1 as the second digit)?

Comment: @ 0xA3 and Jimmy Hoffa -- thanks, I was wondering why 0000000000 isnt correct. I was loosing the leading zeros as mentioned.

Comment: Besides the problem with the leading zero, you also cannot be sure that the number fit in 19 digits. In almost all countries except the US it is allowed to append an extension number to the phone line number.

Comment: @IanH: umm... We do that in the US also. And as http://stackoverflow.com/users/3146/ will tell you, sometimes we like using letters.

Comment: @James: In the US the total length of the number is fixed. So, if you want longer extension numbers, you need a shorter (and thus more expensive) line number. In other countries you are allowed to use an extension number (almost) as long as you want. E.g in Germany the area code is usually 4 digits, the line 8 - and you are free to use a 6 digit (or even more) extension. Together with an international prefix (two or three digits) the number does not fit in a 64bit int.

Comment: @IanH: No, we just do it in two part.  First we dial the first 10 digits, then a voice ask for the extension, and we dial the rest. (Second part handled by the business instead of the phone company)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you really want an integer?  A phone number has no meaning as an integer.

Try this if you are using a string:

```
string fixedString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"[()\s-]", "");
```

If you don't know what kind of characters could be in the string then try this:

```
string fixedString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"[^\d]", "");
```

Comment: in a database with billions of phone numbers, it could foreseeably save disk space to store as an int vs a string, doing the int->string conversion in C#. BTW ripping off your regex, I can never remember regexes :)

Comment: Maybe a safer approach would be to strip out all non-numeric characters?

`Regex.Replace(yourString, @"[^0-9]", "")`

Comment: @ngroot. That's what `\d` does. Personally, I've always preferred the non short-cut: `"[^0-9]"` instead of the `\d` notation.

Comment: @ngroot - I agree, that is what I did in the second example except that I used the character class `\d` as a shortcut for `0-9`.

Comment: For something non regex (because then you have two problems) there is: `string fixedString = string.Join(string.Empty, yourString.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)));`

Answer (score 0):

```
Int64 somePhone;
Int64.TryParse(Regex.Replace(yourString, @"[()\s-)]", ""), out somePhone)
```

Comment: Regex is a more readable alternative, which takes less characters to type.

Comment: @Leonid: but I can never remember regexes.. updated. And regex's more readable? What are you, a perl developer? :P

Comment: Now fix the part about `Int64` vs. `int` and how (919) 555-1212 would overflow.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: Yeah I was thinking about that, but thought there were more digits in 2 billion than there are I guess. Next time I'll use my fingers and count them..

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it the old-fashioned but eminently readable way:

```
    string Strip(string arg)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in arg.ToCharArray())
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

It's also very slightly faster then RegEx (0.449 sec vs 0.472 sec for 10000 interations).0

Comment: If you're going to do this, at least use char.IsDigit(c) instead of c >= '0' and c <= '9'.

Answer (score 0):

Or for the sake of brevity & readibility (to us less-seasoned programmers :-) )

```
    public static string GimmeNumbers(this string arg)
    {
        return new string(arg.ToCharArray().Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
    }
```

usage:

```
    string phoneNo = "(000) 000-0000".GimmeNumbers();
```

or alternatively,

```
    public static int GimmeNumbers(this string arg)
    {
        return int.Parse(new string(arg.ToCharArray().Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()));
    }
```

... actually, thinking about it it's not *that* readable :-)